# Directly open the "Set the time and date" dialog in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, shortcuts, date-time

For testing purposes, occasionally,  I need to change the date and time of the OS. I would really like to have a direct access to the window which allows me to do just that. (In windows 10, you have to do some extra steps, which I prefer to skip: click to clock (bottom right), select 'Date and time settings', select another option and then you get into a new window, where you have to click the 'Set the time and date', and only then you get the 'Date and Time' window - the red window)

Is there a way to open the red window (see the image bellow) by just double clicking a shortcut?

[image]

Comment: if you just want to set the date time then there's no need to open that dialog. You can do that entirely from the command line

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a shortcut pointing to timedate.cpl

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer (it works) and for your recommendation.

Answer (score 5):

You can run `timedate.cpl`. Or you can run a cmd and type 'time' or 'date' to set them.

Answer (score 2):

Save this command in bat file

```
%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL timedate.cpl,,0
```

or this one save this command in bat file

```
%windir%\explorer.exe ms-settings:dateandtime
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. (1) regarding the first solution, could detail what ",,0" does? (2) the second command does not open the (red) window I wanted (I'm using win10 ver1909 build18363.1379)

Comment: i find it in https://help.ivanti.com/res/help/en_US/IWC/10.4/Help/Content/20030.htm

Comment: The ,,0 means it passes 0 as the second argument to timedate.cpl